# Can a Familiar use a Tentacle Rod?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, familiars

Based on my understanding, activating a [Tentacle Rod](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/tentacle-rod) requires the "Use an Object" action. As a 3rd level warlock with Pact of the Chain and an imp familiar, can I order my imp to carry and activate a Tentacle Rod to attack enemies?

Comment: Thanks for asking! Welcome to the stack and please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate.

Comment: There are some related question: "[Can a familiar attune and wear or use a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107328)", "[Can a familiar use a magic item to cast a concentration spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159527)", and "[Does a spell that requires an attack roll count as an “attack” for familiars?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60137)", though I *do* believe yours is a different case then the ones above.

Answer (score 13):

### Yes.

The Tentacle Rod does not actually cause the wielder to make attacks. The *tentacles* attack, on the wielder's command:

> While holding the rod, you can use an action to direct each tentacle to attack a creature you can see within 15 feet of you.

Note that it doesn't matter whether this is an Attack action, a Use an Object action, an item-specific action, or any other kind. Familiars can't attack using *any* action, or by any other means (such as opportunity attacks)*. For example, they couldn't cast *green-flame blade*, because it requires making a melee attack. But the Tentacle Rod is special: you're not attacking with it, just holding it and pointing at targets.

*Pact of the Chain familiars do get a narrow exception to that, but it's not relevant here.

Comment: If you want you could quote the items actual description: "While holding the rod, you can use an action to direct **each tentacle to attack** a creature you can see within 15 feet of you. **Each tentacle makes a melee attack roll** with a +9 bonus. On a hit, **the tentacle deals 1d6 bludgeoning damage.** If **you hit a target with all three tentacles**, it must make a DC 15 Constitution saving throw..."

Comment: @Medix2 Sure, why not.

Comment: I see that the tentacles make the attacks, but a target only makes the saving throw if **you** hit it with all three tentacles, not *if the **rod** hits it*, or *if all three tentacles hit it*. I think a case could be made the other way here.