# Does the Tentacle of the Deeps get bonus damage from Spirit Shroud?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

Does the Fathomless' Tentacle deal extra damage from the Spirit Shroud spell as it is you doing the attack via the tentacle?  If so does the target have to be within 10 feet of both the warlock and the tentacle?

> **Tentacle of the Deeps:** As a bonus action, you create a 10-foot-long tentacle at a point you can see within 60 feet of you.  When you create the tentacle, you can make a melee spell attack against one creature within 10 feet of it.  On a hit, the target takes ld8 cold damage, and its speed is reduced by 10 feet until the start of your next turn. -- Tashas p.72

> **Spirit Shroud:** Until the spell ends, any attack you make deals ld8 extra damage when you hit a creature within 10 feet of you. -- Tashas p.108

Comment: Related: "[Does activating a Tentacle Rod break the invisibility spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170715)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes, if the target is within 10 feet of the warlock.

Tentacles of the Deep says:

> When you create the tentacle, *you can make a melee spell attack* against one creature within 10 feet of it.

Spirit Shroud says:

> *any attack you make* deals 1d8 extra damage when you hit a creature *within 10 feet of you.*

When you attack with the tentacle *you* are making an attack, so it qualifies for Spirit Shroud since Spirit Shroud says “any attack you make”. As long as the target creature is within 10 feet of you, attacks with the tentacle will benefit from Spirit Shroud.